# Mysql server export issues?

Tags: mysql

I am using the following command to export thedabase,however i can't find the FILE.sql file after executing the command.Where is it stored?

```
# mysqldump -u username -ppassword database_name > FILE.sql
```

Comment: are you checking in the directory on which you are running the command? do you have write permissions on that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try removing the space between -u and username:

```
mysqldump -uusername -ppassword database_name > FILE.sql
```

The FILE.sql shall be stored in the same folder where you execute the command.
If it is uknown for you, try specifying complete path to the file, i.e.:

```
mysqldump -uusername -ppassword database_name > $HOME/FILE.sql
```

Then you shall have `FILE.sql` in your HOME directory.

Comment: There's no need to remove the space between `-u` and `username` (I use `mysqldump` every day)

Comment: @Barranka you are right. Then again, the file shall be located in the same directory you were while executing the command.

Comment: which leads me to the question I've posted as a comment to the OP. The only reason I can think for the file not being written in the same directory is because the user has no permissions to write on that directory.

Comment: how to check the current dicrectory ... do you guys mean the program files(x86).No,It's not in it.@Barranka